# Pass props or data beteween components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon friends, 
My pages and components are arranged in the main class of my application, can I pass some results from any component or page to the main class and get this property from main class to any other component.
To describe question well I will show an example:

**This is my main class App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Pages/HomePage";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import PaymentStatus from "./Pages/PaymentStatus";


class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
};

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <NavBar/>
                <Route name={'Home'} exact path={'/'} component={HomePage}/>
                <Route name={'PaymentStatus'} exact path={'/payment-status/:tId'} component={PaymentStatus}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Now my navigation bar component: **NavBar.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class NavBar extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
};

_makeSomething =async() => {
  // Somw function that returns something
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id={"myNavbar"}>
                <div>
                    <a onClick={()=>{this._makeSomething()}} href={'/'}/> Home</a>
                    <a onClick={()=>{this._makeSomething()}} href={"/payment-status"} />Payment Status</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
};

async componentDidMount() {
 console.log(this.props.match.params.tId)
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id={"main"}>
                <div>
                    <p>This is home page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

**PaymentStatusPage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class PaymentStatusPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
};

async componentDidMount() {
 console.log(this.props.match.params.tId)
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id={"status"}>
                <div>
                    <p>This is payment Status Page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PaymentStatusPage;
```

Now here is the question:
Can I pass to **App.js** events (or props) when **HomePage.js** or **PaymentStatusPage.js** or when something was changed in **NavBar.js** 
Also, want pass received peprops to any component.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can decalare method in class App and then pass it to another component via props.
For example 
Then you can call this method in MyComponent and pass some value to it. This is the way you pass value from subcomponent to parent component. In method in App you can simply use setState.
What's left to do is to pass this new state attribute to another component via props.
To pass value to component, while using  you have to change

```
<Route component={SomeComponent}
```

To

```
<Route render={() => <SomeComponent somethingChanged={this.somethingChangedMethodInAppClass}}/>
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: You can also use Redux to externalize state and reuse it in child components

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

- Keep all of your state **in your parent component**, App, and **pass any props down to your children component**, even actions that could update the parent state. If another children uses that state, then that child will be rerendered too.

  - Manage your state with **Redux** and make it available for all your components.

I created a small example out of your scenario.

In this example, the `App` component has a state with a property called `title` and a function that is passed down via props to the `Navbar`.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {
      title: "Home Page"
    };
  }

  _makeSomething = title => {
    this.setState({ title: title });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar clicked={this._makeSomething} />
        <Route
          name={"Home"}
          exact
          path={"/"}
          component={() => <HomePage title={this.state.title} />}
        />
        <Route
          name={"PaymentStatus"}
          exact
          path={"/payment-status/:tId"}
          component={() => <PaymentStatus title={this.state.title} />}
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The components `HomePage` and `PaymentStatus` will get that title as props from the `App`'s state and `NavBar` will get the `_makeSomething` function as props. So far, all that function does is update the state's title.

```js
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={"myNavbar"}>
          <NavLink
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.clicked("Home Page");
            }}
            to={"/"}
          >
            {" "}
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.clicked("Payment Page");
            }}
            to={"/payment-status/1"}
          >
            Payment Status
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the `Navbar`, when the function I passed down from `App` as props is clicked, it will go all the way back to the `App` component again and run `_makeSomething`, which will change the App's `title`.

In the mantime, the components `HomePage` and `PaymentStatus` received `title` as props, so when the state's title is changed, these two children component will change too, since their render function relies on `this.props.title`.

For example, `HomePage`:

```js
class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params.tId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={"main"}>
          <p>This is {this.props.title}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Like I said before, by keeping your state in the parent component and sending down to the children component just what they need, you should be able to accomplish what you need.

A note: I did change the `anchor` tag from `<a>` to `NavLink` which is what you're supposed to use with react-router-dom if you don't want a complete refresh of the page.

The full code can be found here:

[image: Edit bold-hugle-wd2o1]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Context`. With this you can pass an object from a `Provider` to a `Consumer`and even override properties with nested providers: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

AppContext.js

```
 export const AppContext = React.createContext({})
```

App.js

```
    someFunction = ()=>{
       //implement it
    }

    render() {
        const appContext = {
            someFunction: this.someFunction
        }
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>
              <Router>
                  <NavBar/>
                  <Route name={'Home'} exact path={'/'} component={HomePage}/>
                  <Route name={'PaymentStatus'} exact path={'/payment-status/:tId'} component={PaymentStatus}/>
              </Router>
            </AppContext>
        );
    }
```

Homepage.js

```
class HomePage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.state = {};
};

async componentDidMount() {
 console.log(this.props.match.params.tId)
 this.props.appContext.someFunction(); //calls the function of the App-component
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id={"main"}>
                <div>
                    <p>This is home page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default (props) => (
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    {(appContext)=>(
     <HomePage {...props} appContext={appContext}/>
    )}
  </AppContext.Consumer>
)
```

You can also use this mechanic with function components. I'm normally encapsulating the Consumer to an extra component. So all values available for the component as normal property and not just inside the rendered components.